# TypeScript Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type X

Tags: typescript

I have a helper function that removes duplicates from array

```
export const removeDublicatesFromArray = (
  array: IRegulations[],
  key: string
) => {
  return [
    ...new Map(array.map((item: IRegulations) => [item[key], item])).values(),
  ]
}
```

And TS gives me an error on `[item[key]`.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IRegulations'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IRegulations'
```

I did a research and fixed this error passing
`Record<string, string>[]` instead of `IRegulations[]` but it broke the code where this function is used.

Any way I can handle this error with these types?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w2EP1W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  Also, when you say "broke the code where this function is used" you should include enough of that code to show others what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve the issue

```js
export const removeDublicatesFromArray = (
  array: IRegulations[],
  key: keyof IRegulations
) => {
  return [
    ...new Map(array.map((item: IRegulations) => [item[key], item])).values(),
  ]
}
```

The problem you are seeing here is due to the type of `key` being string. You see you are allowing the caller of `removeDublicatesFromArray` to pass any string, that may not be a property of `IRegulations` so, it may fails. The caller must ensure that they are passing the right key for it to work and hence you need to constraint the type of `key` as `keyof IRegulations`

PS: I did not check the logic, I just fixed the type error and explained the thought process behind it.